# Chrome Extension : How to handle disable and enable event from browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to run a callback after extension is disabled/enabled from chrome browser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Chrome management API()'s

- [chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo info) {})](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onEnabled)
- [chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo info) {})](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onDisabled)

notifies changes of enable and disable of extensions.

Ensure you have

```
"permissions": [
    "management"
  ],
```

in your `manifest.json`

#### Sample Demonstration

```
chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ExtensionInfo));
});
```

P.S : An extension on its own can't monitor when it gets disabled. You'd need a second extension to monitor this. From extension's and user's perspectives, disabling extension has exactly the same effect as closing a browser.

For more information refer [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html).

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but I'm not getting either `onInstalled` or `onStartup` when my extension is (disabled  and then) re-enabled.  (Whereas I do get onInstalled on Reload (Ctrl-R), and I get onStartup when the browser opens up.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @ErikEidt because `onInstalled` and `onStartup` do not fire when you enable/disable the extension.

Comment: Bummer, that means an extension must constantly check to see if it is initialized, because it might have just been silently enabled, no?

Comment: [Not really](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68564340/1509695), as it can get register for its own `onEnabled` event ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is [indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984356/1509695) a sibling `chrome.management` api namespace where `onEnabled` is available, and it does fire for me as expected (when disabling and enabling in developer mode, as well as when not in developer mode).

You can do something like this:

```
chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(start);
```

But note that your manifest will require an extra permission for using this API as already mentioned in the original answer. [See here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#manifest) for details in the documentation.

Using `chrome.management.onEnabled` seems to be a real sanity saver when flipping your extension on and off as a developer, and all else equal sounds like a good idea for when your users do that as well.

So as of now for my development workflow, I currently trigger my extension's initialization logic on three events in my extension's service worker script which my manifest point at, so that reloading the extension as well as disabling and enabling it all trigger the initialization:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(start);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(start);
chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(start);
```

Whereby `start` is a function containing my initialization logic.

It's a little non-obvious (to me) why handling its own enablement event, which is basically when the extension is launched, would not be available without the extension requiring management permission. Perhaps there is a different event that can be used for that, within the `chrome.runtime` api, or a more correct blueprint for this which I haven't quite figured out yet. If you know a better way, glad to learn about it.

Comment: Why can't you just write `start()` at the top of your service worker?