# How to set callback onDisable chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, callback

I need help to create a callback when my chrome extension in disabled. I have already referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979781/chrome-extension-how-to-handle-disable-and-enable-event-from-browser) that says about adding a listener onDisable. But this doesnt work for own. When my extension is disabled, it does nothing. There is an answer in this link that says we can not do this, But I am still hoping that I can find something new on this topic. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that `management` API cannot catch the extension itself being disabled or uninstalled. This is by design - you don't want extensions to be able to stop you from removing them.

There is no event you can process when either of those happen.

There is an exception in that your content scripts [continue to run in an "orphaned" state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895377/sending-message-from-a-background-script-to-a-content-script-then-to-a-injected) and can detect that the parent extension is not there anymore by poking at Chrome API (and possibly `onDisconnect` event on a [Port object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port)), but at that point the content script can't do much.

---

Curiously, there is no event that will fire on *enabling* either. This can cause problems when an update happened while an extension was disabled and relies on `runtime.onInstalled` event to perform upgrades.